# Wipe an entire iCloud Photo Library using Windows

Tags: icloud, photos

Old Method:

1. Click 'Select Photos' at the top
2. Select the very first photo
3. Scroll all the way to the bottom
4. Hold the Shift key and click the last photo (this will select everything in between)
5. Click 'Delete' at the top

**This does not work anymore**

I need a quick way of deleting 10,000 photos from my iCloud without selecting each one manually using Windows.